# DNN Module installation

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

Is it possible to "install" a module just by pasting the file of the module and just paste it into the DesktopModules folder and have the modules working on the website?

If not, is there a way where I can export the whole module from one system and install it onto another system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a module package for this module? (when you click the edit pen for the extension, you should find a "Create package" button on the top right).

Take care to include the assembly/assemblies needed, and also the Sql Server scripts to install the module correctly (often found in the module folder under Providers/DataProvider/SqlDataProvider/*.SqlDataProvider). There might be other files in the module folder (images, css, etc), be sure to include them in the package, then try to create it. You will find the ZIP file under /install/Modules then, move it away from there somewhere on your local file system (otherwise the installer might try to install it with the next update). Then try to update the extension in a testing system, check if it works and you're done. If there are errors it might be that you are missing some files that have to be included. Check the error messages, and restart.

Comment: By creating this module package, I would be able to use that zip file created to install the module elsewhere right?

Comment: There is no guarantee for it. But chances are not bad, even with a lot of trial and error. I would check if there is a .dnn file in the module's directory, that could help finding out which files are needed...

Comment: For more information about the .dnn file (aka manifest) check out https://dnndocs.com/content/tutorials/modules/beginning-module-development/wrapping-up/index.html#the-manifest

Comment: Is it possible to change the output folder of the created package? I currently do not have access to the server and i need a way to gete my hands on the file.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a way using the /Install/Module/ folder (put ZIP file there, then call /install/install.aspx?mode=installresources) If you are on an old version of DNN (7 and earlier?) you can still use this. But you've got a load of security issues that should drive you to upgrade.

I don't know of a good way to do this now. For security purposes DNN removes the Install resources after an upgrade.

IF you already have the module installed in both locations, you could copy the resources for the file from server to server (DLL in the BIN folder and the contents of the desktopmodules folder) assuming you don't have any MANIFEST file changes that need registered.

Comment: The module I am talking about is a Responsive FAQ module which the previous developers have gotten from www.ModuleDNN.com, but I discovered that the website is not operating anymore, so, I am unable to get the necessary installation files, but it is still running on the website.

Unless there is a way to install it without the zip file that would be great.

Or if there are any open-source responsive FAQ modules that are similar to that, that are recommended, that would be even better.